# How can I calculate the percentage of empty values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`, from which I know there are empty values, i.e. '' (blank spaces).
I want to calculate the percentage per column of those observations and replace them with `NaN`.

To get the percentage I've tried:

```
for col in df:
   empty = round((df[df[col]] == '').sum()/df.shape[0]*100, 1)
```

I have a similar code which calculates the zeros, which does work:

```
zeros = round((df[col] == 0).sum()/df.shape[0]*100, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) for test missing values (but not empty spaces):

```
nans = round(df[col].isna().sum()/df.shape[0]*100, 1)
```

Solution should be simplify with `mean`:

```
nans = round(df[col].isna().mean()*100, 1)
```

For replace empty spaces or spaces to `NaN`s use:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

nans = round(df[col].isna().mean()*100, 1)
```

If need test all columns:

```
nans = df.isna().mean().mul(100).round()
```

Comment: Would this account for values that are falsely codified, i.e. that are missing values but aren't codified with NaN, but with '' (blank space)?

Comment: @LeLuc - So missing values are not blank spaces, it is something different. But is possible replace them to missing values,give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer to your problem will be :

```
for col in df:
    empty_avg = round(df[col].isna().mean()*100, 1) # This line is to find the average of empty values.

df = df[df != ''] # This will replace all the empty values with NaN.
```